# Create a random folder in file system and save downloaded file iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

From server I am downloading a large number of files and I want to save them into local file system.
But the thing is many files will have same name, so I want create a random folder and save each file into different directory.

so the structure should be homeDirectory-->randomFolder1-->file1, homeDirectory-->randomfolder2-->file2.

How can I do this in iOS? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code to create folders. Name these folders with unique timeStamps in the App's Document directory

```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];  // to get unique name for your folder

NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:timestamp];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
```

After creating this folder, save your downloaded file in the folder.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using UUID for the random file names:

```
- (NSString *) newImageName
{
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid));
    CFRelease(uuid);
    return uuidString;
}
```

*Update* Since iOS 6 and OS X 10.8 this is simplified by using NSUUID:

```
- (NSString *) newImageName
{
    return [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create the folder with a random number in the name. To avoid duplicate random numbers you could add a time stamp.

```
NSData *yourFileContents;
NSString *yourFileName;

NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 10000000;
NSTimeInterval time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *folderName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Folder-%u-%f", 
   randomNumber, time * 10000];

NSArray *paths = 
  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *folderPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourFileName];

[yourFileContents writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```